# Create endpoint in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, endpoint

I have this endpoint defined in my web.config file and it works fine. Now I need to change some values depending of what service i am going to use. My endpoint looks like this.

```
    <endpoint address="https://www.yyy.com/services" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="VehicleQuotationManagementServiceBinding" contract="VehicleQuotationManagementService.VehicleQuotationManagementServicePortType" name="VehicleQuotationManagementServicePort">
    <headers>
      <wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">ws://bla.com/CSP/UsedCars/VehicleQuotationManagementService/V1</wsa:To>
      <wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">ws://bla.com/CSP/UsedCars/VehicleQuotationManagementService/V1/ProcessAliveTest</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">1111</wsa:MessageID>
      <vwa:Country xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" wsa:IsReferenceParameter="true" xmlns:vwa="http://xmldefs.bla.com/Technical/Addressing/V1">SE</vwa:Country>
      <vwa:Brand xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" wsa:IsReferenceParameter="true" xmlns:vwa="http://xmldefs.bla.com/Technical/Addressing/V1">V</vwa:Brand>
      <vwa:System xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" wsa:IsReferenceParameter="true" xmlns:vwa="http://xmldefs.bla.com/Technical/Addressing/V1">GWB</vwa:System>
    </headers>
  </endpoint>
```

Can someone help me create this endpoint in c# code?

Comment: Why do you want to create it in C#? It's a good idea to use the xml format as it becomes pretty easy to exchange the endpoints when necessary.

Comment: Are you hosting the service yourself, i.e. in a windows service? The classes are all located in the `System.ServiceModel` namespace, the Endpoint is `System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint` i think.

Comment: @Animal I disagree. XML based config is an extra area where you can get it wrong. Invoking the compiler on something complex like WCF Endpoints in my opinion is a good thing. PLUS if you are using a shared contract dll you might as well share the bindings via code as well.

Comment: Problem solved, by having multiple endpoints in my web.config i could point out wich to use when i instantiate the web service